# Can't create delegated model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have Client model and a Detail model. Detail model must be created together with Client.

```
class Client < AdminUser

  has_one :detail, class_name: 'ClientDetail', autosave: true
  delegate  :phone,:phone=, :name, :name=, to: :detail, prefix: true
  after_initialize :prebuild_details

  attr_accessible :detail_phone, :detail_name

  validates :detail_phone, :detail_name, presence: true

  private
  def prebuild_details
    logger.info 'WE GONNA CALL SOME BUILD!!! 'if detail.nil?
    build_detail if detail.nil?
  end

end

class ClientDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  attr_accessible :phone, :name
end
```

And the Detail attributes are empty! :(

```
s =  Client.new(email: Faker::Internet.email, password: password,password_confirmation: password, detail_name: Faker::Lorem.word,detail_phone: Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number )
WE GONNA CALL SOME BUILD!!! 
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> #<Client id: nil, email: ....>
irb(main):006:0> s.valid?
=> false
irb(main):007:0> s.detail_phone
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> s.detail_name
=> nil
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Run `s.errors` right after `s.valid?` to see what the problem is.

Comment: Where is the definition of that `build_detail` method you're calling from within `prebuild_details`?

Comment: @messages={:detail_phone=>["translation missing: ru.activerecord.errors.models.client.attributes.detail_phone.blank"], :detail_name=>["translation missing: ru.activerecord.errors.models.client.attributes.detail_name.blank"]}>

it's a dynamic method http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association-reference

Comment: It works if you do `s = Client.new` and then `s.assign_attributes(:detail_name => "name", :detail_phone => "444")`. Does that work out for you?